# AngularJS issue with ng-change and select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a weird issue where ng-change isn't working properly with ng-select. I have attached a fiddle that recreates this problem. Picking any option defaults to the "This Year" option.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select ng-model="selectedRange" ng-change="dateFilter()">
          <option value="week" selected>This week</option>
          <option value="month">This month</option>
          <option value="year">This year</option>
          <option value="custom">Custom</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

The above is my view. And below is the ng-change function that the select tag triggers.

```
$scope.dateFilter = function () {
  $scope.customDate = false;
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date();

  if ($scope.selectedRange == 'week') {
    $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
    $scope.searchStartDate.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
  }
  if ($scope.selectedRange = 'month') {
    $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
    $scope.searchStartDate.setMonth(oneWeekAgo.getMonth() - 1);
  }
  if ($scope.selectedRange = 'year') {
    $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
    $scope.searchStartDate.setYear(oneWeekAgo.getYear() - 1);
  }

  if ($scope.selectedRange == 'custom') {
    $scope.customDate = true;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/1087/

Thanks for the help

Comment: To avoid the error that you have, developers usually have the value on the LHS - for example, `'year' === $scope.selectedRange` - That way, if you accidentally use the equality operator (=) instead of the comparison one (==  / ===), you get an error.

Comment: Just so you know the operator was only a typo/small part of the issue. The real issue seems to be that the OP never passes in the value selected on ng-change. Simply changing the operator does not get his script working

Comment: Bill Huang can you please accept an answer, this is done by clicking the checkbox next to the solution that solved your problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In month, year condition you are missing '==' operator

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dateFilter = function () {
        //alert("Hello");
      $scope.customDate = false;
      var oneWeekAgo = new Date();

      if ($scope.selectedRange == 'week') {
          alert("week");
        $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
        $scope.searchStartDate.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
      }
      if ($scope.selectedRange == 'month') {
          alert("month");
        $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
        $scope.searchStartDate.setMonth(oneWeekAgo.getMonth() - 1);
      }
      if ($scope.selectedRange == 'year') {
          alert("year");
        $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
        $scope.searchStartDate.setYear(oneWeekAgo.getYear() - 1);
      }

      if ($scope.selectedRange == 'custom') {
          alert("custom");
        $scope.customDate = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `=` with `==`.

In your code, `$scope.selectedRange` will always be set to 'year', and the result of the expression `$scope.selectedRange = 'year'` would be truthful value thus the following code always executed:

```
$scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
$scope.searchStartDate.setYear(oneWeekAgo.getYear() - 1);
```

Please change `=` to `==` for the month and year block, then problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript should read like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.dateFilter = function (selectedRangeVal) {
      $scope.customDate = false;
      var oneWeekAgo = new Date();

// I would make this a switch or function called like this: dateFns[selectedRangeVal]();

      if (selectedRangeVal == 'week') {
        $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
        $scope.searchStartDate.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7);
      }
      if (selectedRangeVal = 'month') {
        $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
        $scope.searchStartDate.setMonth(oneWeekAgo.getMonth() - 1);
      }
      if (selectedRangeVal = 'year') {
        $scope.searchStartDate = new Date();
        $scope.searchStartDate.setYear(oneWeekAgo.getYear() - 1);
      }

      if (selectedRangeVal == 'custom') {
        $scope.customDate = true;
      }
    }
}
```

And your markup stays almost exactly the same, the solution was by adding {{ selectedRange }} and passing it into the controllers dateFilter(selection)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <select class="atom-offerFilter--filterDate atom-widget--header__select" style="width: 150px; font-family: ' Museo', sans-serif;" ng-model="selectedRange" ng-change="dateFilter(selectedRange)"> 



              <option value="week" selected>This week</option>
              <option value="month">This month</option>
              <option value="year">This year</option>
              <option value="custom">Custom</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

You don't need to compare the $scope val, instead pass in the changed value on ng-change to your controller function dateFilter(selectedValue).

Also don't forget == is usually not what you want for comparisons and = never is. Almost always use === unless you wish to use javascripts built in type coercion.

Your were soooo close! http://jsfiddle.net/geub5cxk/1/